# с++ и виртуальное наследование

Tags: c++, наследование

Необходимо создать базовый класс который будет иметь 4 наследника. Вся проблема в том, что мне нужен базовый класс в одном экземпляре, так как там будут храниться указатели на наследуемые объекты + есть наследуемые классы которые не будут создаваться сразу и мне надо определять какие будут созданы а какие нет по массиву.

Вопрос заключается в следующем: 
Есть код:

```
header

class dataBase
{
public:
std::vector<dataBase*> data;
dataBase();
int a=0;
static int sl;

};

class type1 :  public virtual dataBase
{

public:
type1();
int b;
};

class type2:  public virtual dataBase
{

public:
type2();
int c;
};
```

где в реализации для каждого:

```
int dataBase::sl=0;
dataBase::dataBase()
{
sl++;
a=sl;
}

type1::type1(){
data.insert(data.end(), this);
b=a;
}

type2::type2()
{
data.insert(data.end(), this);
c=a;
}
```

Вся проблема в том, что определяя наследник класса виртуальным, как я понял это дает возможность не создавать копию базового класса, все равно создает копию. Если посмотреть на счетчик статической переменной, то он будет указывать на то, что базовый класс был создан два раза.

А если в переменную а записать с наследуемого класса type1, то в type2 при изъятии получил другое число (random, это если отбросить код конструктора.)

Прошу, помогите разобраться. Спасибо за ранее.

Comment: Напишите что именно вы хотите получить, я подозреваю ошибку в архитектуре (возможно нужно не наследование а композиция к примеру). Или просто использовать статическое поле как вариант. Но без понимания задачи я так сразу не подскажу.

Comment: Добрый день. Я хотел бы иметь возможность хранить структуру данных (в каждом классе разные переменные) в памяти и так же хотелось бы иметь управление данными с одного класса. ( например: записать в текстовый файл поля класса )  Спасибо за ранее.

Comment: Для того, чтобы получить эффект "не создания копии базового класса" от виртуального наследования нужно: 1) как минимум 3 уровня иерархии классов, 2) множественное наследование.

Comment: спасибо за информацию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> как я понял это дает возможность не создавать копию базового класса,
>   все равно создает копию

**Он гарантирует, что среди всех предков данного класса, любой предок будет создан только один в иерархии для данного класса.** 
У вас же каждый type1 и type2 имеет по ОДНОМУ уникальному предку, у каждого класса эти предки уникальны, соответственно, каждый предок будет создан для каждого класса потомка. Поэтому у вас здесь virtual не играет никакой роли. 
virtual может имеет значение только при множественном наследовании, когда у класса будет несколько предков, и мы хотим, чтобы в иерархии наследования не было копий предков.

Пример:

```
class A {  };
class B: public A {};
class C: public A {};
class D: public B, public C {};
```

В иерархии класса D имеются следующие потомки: ***B, A, C, A*** 
Сделав вот так

```
class A {  };
class B: public virtual A {};
class C: public virtual  A {};
class D: public B, public C {};
```

мы говорим, что нам в иерархии класса D необходимо иметь только один потомок А, соответственно вместо создания 2 экземпляров класса А, будет создан **ТОЛЬКО ОДИН ЕДНИСТВЕННЫЙ**: ***A, B, C***

Есть предположение, что вам здесь нужен static для вашего поля базового класса, который будет вам гарантировать, что оно будет общим для всех экземпляров классов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Теперь все стало ясно.